# Remove result set doesnt meet criteria

Tags: mysql

This is part of a query result :
[image]

I'm going to add a constraint to my query to remove the orders that don't have an `invoice_type = final`, so the first three rows should be removed and the last three rows should remain in the result.

How should I do that?

Comment: Use a self-join, join the table to itself with a condition to match the order_id but have the final type filtered for the second instance.

Comment: Can you provide the table structure(s) for obtaining your result set? SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table(s)\G - It's difficult to see straight off why you just can't add "AND invoice_type = 'final'" to your query? Also, please provide the text of that query.

Comment: ok,ill add more details soon, but about :  *`why you just can't add "AND invoice_type = 'final'" to your query`*, i should say because if an order has one final invoice then i need all invoices of that order NOT just the invoice that is of final type , and if order doesnt have any final invoice then i dont need that order at all , the **All or nothing** rule!

Answer (score 2):

I think this query will work for you :

```
select 
  order_item_id,
  order_id,
  invoice_id,
  invoice_type
from your_table
where order_item_id in 
(select order_item_id from your_table where invoice_type = 'final' group by order_item_id)
```

Comment: @alex you can also remove group by clause .. It will work

Comment: thanks, it seems both `where in` and `join` will do the job, but i dont know which is faster?

Comment: @alex Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to find out. It depends on your schema and server version.